# How do I check if the path from a node to another has a depth equal to a given one in a graph in OCaml?

Tags: recursion, graph, functional-programming, ocaml

First of all, I'm sorry for how I wrote my question.

Anyway, I'm trying to write a function in OCaml that, given a graph, a max depth, a starting node, and another node, returns the list of the nodes that make the path but only if the depth of it is equal to the given one. However, I can't implement the depth part.
This is what I did:

```
let m = [(1, 2, "A"); (2, 3, "A");
         (3, 1, "A"); (2, 4, "B"); 
         (4, 5, "B"); (4, 6, "C"); 
         (6, 3, "C"); (5, 7, "D");
         (6, 7, "D")]

let rec vicini n = function 
    [] -> []
  | (x, y, _)::rest -> 
      if x = n then y :: vicini n rest
      else if y = n then x :: vicini n rest
      else vicini n rest

exception NotFound

let raggiungi m maxc start goal = 
  let rec from_node visited n = 
    if List.mem n visited then raise NotFound
    else if n = goal then [n]
    else n :: from_list (n :: visited) (vicini n m)
  and from_list visited = function 
      [] -> raise NotFound
    | n::rest ->
        try from_node visited n
        with NotFound -> from_list visited rest
  in start :: from_list [] (vicini start m)
```

I know I have to add another parameter that increases with every recursion and then check if its the same as the given one, but I don't know where

Answer (score 3):

I am not going to solve your homework, but I will try to teach you how to use recursion.

In programming, especially functional programming, we use recursion to express iteration. In an iterative procedure, there are things that change with each step and things that remain the same on each step. An iteration is well-founded if it has an end, i.e., at some point in time, the thing that changes reaches its foundation and stops. The thing that changes on each step, is usually called an induction variable as the tribute to the mathematical induction. In mathematical induction, we take a complex construct and deconstruct it step by step. For example, consider how we induct over a list to understand its length,

```
let rec length xs = match xs with 
  | [] -> 0
  | _ :: xs -> 1 + length xs
```

Since the list is defined inductively, i.e., a `list` is either an empty list `[]` or a pair of an element `x` and a `list`, `x :: list` called a cons. So to discover how many elements in the list we follow its recursive definition, and deconstruct it step by step until we reach the foundation, which is, in our case, the empty list.

In the example above, our inductive variable was the list and we didn't introduce any variable that will represent the length itself. We used the program stack to store the length of the list, which resulted in an algorithm that consumes memory equivalent to the size of the list to compute its length. Doesn't sound very efficient, so we can try to devise another version that will use a variable passed to the function, which will track the length of the list, let's call it `cnt`,

```
let rec length cnt xs = match xs with
  | [] -> cnt
  | _ :: xs -> length (cnt+1) xs
```

Notice, how on each step we deconstruct the list and increment the `cnt` variable. Here, call to the `length (cnt+1) xs` is the same as you would see in an English-language explanation of an algorithm that will state something like, increment `cnt` by one, set `xs` to the `tail xs` and goto step 1. The only difference with the imperative implementation is that we use arguments of a function and change them on each call, instead of changing them in place.

As the final example, let's devise a function that checks that there's a letter in the first `n` letters in the word, which is represented as a list of characters. In this function, we have two parameters, both are inductive (note that a natural number is also an inductive type that is defined much like a list, i.e., a number is zero or the successor of a number). Our recursion is also well-founded, in fact, it even has two foundations, the 0 length and the empty list, whatever comes first. It also has a parameter that doesn't change.

```
let rec has_letter_in_prefix letter length input =
  length > 0 && match input with
  | [] -> false
  | char :: input ->
    char = letter || has_letter_in_prefix letter (length-1) input
```

I hope that this will help you in understanding how to encode iterations with recursion.